# ActionBar tab - replace list fragment with detail fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm struggling combining a **tabbed ActionBar** and **fragments**.

I'm using **ActionBarSherlock** to display three independent tabs, and my problem relates to the first tab exclusively. It's supposed to display items (called "coupons") in a combination of list and detail view. The other two tabs display different content and do not play a role here.

What I'm doing is the following:

- The main activity creates three fragments for three tabs
- Tab A (a list fragment) populates and renders its list
- For clicks on the list I wrote a callback in the main activity that receives the clicked item's id and exchanges the list fragment with the detail fragment on the tab (at least its supposed to do so)
- In that callback I create the to-be-displayed detail fragment and try to replace the list fragment with it.

Unfortunately I dont get beyond:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f040027
>   for fragment CouponDetailFragment{44f4e310 #1 id=0x7f040027}

I attached the relevant snippets at the end of the question. Any help is highly appreciated.

These are the relevant snippets:

```
public class MyCouponActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements CouponListFragment.Callbacks
```

List fragment:

> ```
> <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>     android:name="foo.bar.CouponListFragment"
>     android:id="@+id/coupon_list"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent" />
> ```

Transaction for fragment exchange:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(final String id) {
    final Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
    arguments.putString(CouponDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
    final CouponDetailFragment fragment = new CouponDetailFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(arguments);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.coupon_list, fragment).commit();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define a fragment in XML, it is fixed and you can't replace it with another fragment in a FragmentTransaction.

Your best bet would be to replace the `<fragment />` with some sort of `ViewGroup`. Don't forget then you'd have to use a FragmentTransaction to add a CouponListFragment in the `onCreate(..)` of your Activity.